# Putting huge blender folder from pc to external harddrive

Tags: blend-files

I'm almost out memory on my computer. I just bought an external harddrive. I have a huge gb blender folder on my pc. is there a way to put this file on my external harddrive without losing all the textures? The files still open but all the textures are missing. How do I put it on my harddrive witout this error?

Comment: You can find out where Blender expects to find any missing files by using Blender's File > External Data > Report Missing Files menu with your Blend file open.